# Replace logo on specific wordpress page with css

Tags: css, wordpress

I’m trying to display a different logo for a specific page on my website. I’ve added a CSS rule that targets the specific page id and it swaps the logo successfully but only on Chrome and Safari. But on Firefox and IE it doesn’t swap the logo (it just shows the original one)

```
.page-id-1973 #logo {content: url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/new-logo.png) ;}
```

Could you tell me how to make it Firefox and IE compatible, or is there another way of achieving it?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The [`content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) applies to the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content` is the [wrong css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) to use to apply an image to a node.  That job belongs to `background`:

```
.page-id-1973 #logo {
     background: url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/new-logo.png);
}
```

You could also use `background-image`

If the image you are replacing is in the dom as an `<img>` tag you can do this to hide it and retain the height and width of the original:

```
.page-id-1973 #logo img { visibility: hidden; }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion of using 'background' - even though the new logo now displays, the old one is still overlaid on top of it.

Comment: Try something like:
.page-id-1973 #logo img {
     visibility: hidden;
}

Or, if your replacement image is a different size then, use `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: I'm not having much luck. Would you mind if I DM you the web page to have a quick look at?

Comment: I can't make any promises about getting to it quickly, but, sure, go ahead.

Comment: Did you try:  .page-id-1973 #logo img { visibility: hidden; } ?  I don't see that code in your css.

Comment: All of the css on that page is the css that you originally had.  As stated above, your original css will not accomplish what you want.  You will need to change your css to the css I recommended in order to get the results you are hoping for.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. I missed the 'img' part out when I added visibility hidden. I've put it in now and its working - thanks very much!